# Не выводиться картинки в резметке html

Tags: laravel, png

Не могу понять, как правильно построить путь к изображению/изображениям.

Вот часть разметки:

```
@foreach($images as $item)

    <div>
        <img style="height: 300px; width: 400px" src="{{$item->getImages() }}" alt="">
    </div>


@endforeach
```

Вот модель:

```
 public function getImage()
    {
        if(!$this->thumbnail){
            return asset("no-image.png");
        }
        return asset("uploads/{$this->thumbnail}");

    }

PPTPostController :
public function edit($id)
    {
        $ppt = Pptpost::with('images')->find($id);
        $images = Slide::where('pptpost_id', $id)->get();

        return view('admin.pptpost.edit', compact('ppt', 'images'));


    }
```

В представлении выглядит так:

```
<img style="height: 300px; width: 400px" src="http://sivkov/uploads/thumbnails/2023-05-28/A9dqc2BlLSvAQPgArqyfeGUB0GPPtCoVzkTsLIdQ.jpg" alt="">
```

В БД выглядит так:

```
thumbnails/2023-05-28/kB2eC22w5oT5jILmnWXXrzlJBHNLidN8KXbqpErR.jpg
```

Понимаю, что путь не рабочий, но уже много что перепробовал. Не могу понять, что не так в пути.

Comment: `$item->getImages()` и `public function getImage()` - не смущает разница в названии метода?

Comment: Да, связь есть. Проверял. В верстке один input для модели Slide, которая в себе содержит метод getImages() , связан с таблицей slides в бд, так как их массив изображений; следующий input расчитан на одиночное изображение. В модели Pptpost есть метод getImage() соответсвенно, он связан с табл. pptposts в бд. В общем у меня 2 таблицы бд и 2 модели. Между собой они связаны , я проверял связь хорошая.

Comment: вот моя связь в модели Pptpost :  public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Slide::class, 'pptpost_id');

    }

Comment: Тогда используйте связь свою - `@foreach($ppt->images as $item)` и в контроллере удалить второй запрос - `$images = Slide::where('pptpost_id', $id)->get();`. Проверяйте правильно формируются ссылки и открываются по ним файлы или нет, раньше же открывались?

Comment: Спасибо! Все верно

Answer (score 0):

Все решилось! Просто `public/` добавил в  эти 2 функции.